# How to launch an arduino script via the command prompt (cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arduino-uno

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but does anyone know how to launch an arduino script (.ino) from the cmd? I've already made a .bat script that opens the arduino application:

```
cd\
cd Users\student\Desktop\Me\etch a sketch\StandardFirmata
StandardFirmata.ino
```

but it doesn't actually run the program. Help?

Comment: Have you tried the `start` command (type `start /?` for help)?

Comment: @aschipfl that opens the arduino application (which contains the script), but doesn't run the script itself

Comment: The first couple of answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189306/command-line-arduino-compiling-and-downloading) should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this problem by uploading my code to Arduino then reading serial port and I used this code to send serial commands from my cmd. just save this code as .bat and notice that I am using com6 if you are using something different make sure to change it in the code.

```
mode com6:9600,N,8,1
@echo off
:start
cls
Set /p commands="enter command:"
echo|set /p= %commands% >com6
goto start
```